# How to stop creation of singleton class object using reflection even if I throw exception from private constructor ( without using enums)

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection

As we know that an object can be created using reflection for singleton classes, however to stop it, we usually throw exception from private constructor. Refer to the code below

```
public class SingletonClass {

    private static SingletonClass instance = new SingletonClass();

    private SingletonClass(){
    // this will stop reflection attack..
    if(instance!=null){
        thrown new Exception();
    }
    }   

    public static SingletonClass getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Please correct my understanding, but before invoking constructor to create object using reflection, I can even set instance field as null using reflection itself.. then in that case I can easily create object using reflection and bypass the check inside the constructor...

Is there a way to stop object creation using reflection in this case.. I don't want to use enums...

Comment: "we usually throw exception from private constructor" No we don't. What are you trying to achieve here, why do you need to "protect" this from reflection, what is wrong with enum singleton?

Comment: Also note that it's `throw new Exception()`

Comment: Why dont you use Enum.. Enum is the best way to do singleton in java

Comment: @RC corrected the mistake as pointed by you. However I was only curious to know if using enums is the only way to defend against reflection attack..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't understand why you would be so extremely protecting your objects, people will always be able to call setAccessible() unless you are using java 9, where you can choose to not export your class in your module.